# How bright will Sirius be when it's closest to the solar system?

Tags: observational-astronomy

Preferably in terms of percentage. As a layman, visual apparent magnitude means little to me.

Comment: What's that name?

Comment: How can you express brightness in terms of percentage?

Answer (score 5):

From [Sirius: Brightest Diamond in the Night Sky](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CEk6SZQK0C0C&pg=PA213&lpg=PA213&dq=relative%20motion%20of%20sirius&source=bl&ots=KMbqPxsA0q&sig=A9KHZhHCBcpwcrfTHf7TWQ7eBfU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvqajR2NzOAhXIK8AKHVZ6D5wQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=relative%20motion%20of%20sirius&f=false) by Jay B. Holberg we have current distance of Sirius ~8.5ly, closest approach will be ~6.7ly. The intensity of of light from Sirius assuming constant luminosity scales as distance squared, so the intensity (power per unit area at the eye) at closest approach will be: $\left(8.5/6.7 \right)^2 \approx 1.6$ times that today, which is a change of magnitude from about $-1.4$ to about $ -1.6$

Comment: TLDR: the change will be barely noticeable.

Comment: It would still be measurably dimmer than the brightest 3 planets, but I think a change from -1.6 to -1.4 would be visibly noticeable, especially if you had 2 objects of that brightness side by side.